# How can I make an automatically closing cabinet door?

Tags: cabinets, hinges

I have some kitchen cabinets with inset doors.  My kids are constantly leaving them open and it drives me nuts!  I'm trying to find a hinge to make them automatically close.  I found some "self-closing" hinges, but they apparently just go the "last 1 inch" after the door is pushed closed.  I then found "concealed spring hinges" that might do the trick.  I'd keep the existing hinges for aesthetics and to avoid the sag some reviews complained about.

Question: Are these type of hinges (concealed spring) strong enough to pull the door closed even from a fully opened position as soon as the kid lets go?

Comment: or just add a small spring to the top that pulls them closed and a damper to avoid them slamming shut

Comment: Unless the spring hinge pivot pin(s) align(s) exactly with your existing hinges, they cannot both be installed.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you're trying to keep a door open (say, while moving several items in and out of the cabinet), having it try to close every second without being propped open can be even more frustrating than just training your kids to make sure they clean up after themselves.